# Difference between two dates without leap day

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have Start Date and End Date and I have to get difference between these two dates, but the condition is, I have to exclude 29th Feb if it is leap year. I am able to get difference between two dates using momentJS. But how to exclude 29th feb if it is in that date range.

For Ex:

```js
//For Leap Year
var startDate = moment('2020-02-27')
var endDate = moment('2020-03-01')
console.log('Diff in leap year', endDate.diff(startDate, 'days')); //Result: 3



var startDate1 = moment('2018-02-27')
var endDate1 = moment('2018-03-01')
console.log('Diff in non leap year', endDate1.diff(startDate1, 'days')); //Result: 2
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I am expecting uniform result for leap and non leap year, or simply want to exclude 29th feb from calculation. Difference can be more than a year.

Is there any optimal solution to do it?

Comment: the best you can do is check if is leap year by `startDate.isLeapYear()` and if so, you subtract one more day from result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.isLeapYear()` you can iterate over all the years between date range and get the expected result

```
function dateDiff(startStr, endStr) {
  var startDate = moment(startStr);
  var endDate = moment(endStr);
  var diff = endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');
  for (var year = startDate.year(); year <= endDate.year(); year++) {
    var date = moment(year + '-02-29');
    if (date.isBetween(startDate,endDate) && date.isLeapYear()) {
        diff -= 1;
    }
  }
  return diff;
}

console.log(dateDiff('2020-02-27', '2020-03-01'));
console.log(dateDiff('2018-02-27', '2018-03-01'));
```

Comment: This is working as I expected, any optimal solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can check if it is a leap year using `.isLeapYear()` and if so, you subtract one more day from your result:

```
function diffDates(startDate, endDate) {
  var diff = endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');

  while(startDate < endDate) {
    if(startDate.isLeapYear() && 
      moment(`${startDate.year()}-02-29`).isBetween(startDate, endDate)) {
      diff--;
    }
    startDate.year(startDate.year() + 1);
  }
  return diff;
}

var startDate = moment('2020-02-27')
var endDate = moment('2020-03-01')

console.log('Leap year days diff: ' + diffDates(startDate, endDate)); // 2

startDate = moment('2018-02-27')
endDate = moment('2018-03-01')
console.log('Non leap year days diff: ' + diffDates(startDate, endDate)); // 2

startDate = moment('2019-02-27')
endDate = moment('2020-03-01')
console.log('Between leap year days diff: ' + diffDates(startDate, endDate)); // 367
```

I've added a clause to know if your dates is between feb 29 when is a leap year using `.isBetween()`, and created a `while` loop to subtract 1 from `diff` every time a *leap day* is within interval.

See it working [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQOrNp?editors=1010).

Comment: what about ranges spanning years? 2019-12-31 to 2020-03-01... or large ranges including 1 _or more_ leap years. But this looks good for the simple case

Comment: I'm assuming dates are within same year

Comment: question states difference can be more than a year so probably not a safe assumption for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the `startDate` is a leap year or not using `.isLeapYear()` and then subtract 1 accordingly.

```js
function getDiff(startDate, endDate){
  var isLeapYear = startDate.isLeapYear();
  return endDate.diff(startDate, 'days') - (isLeapYear?1:0);
}


var startDate = moment('2020-02-27')
var endDate = moment('2020-03-01')
console.log('Diff in leap year', getDiff(startDate, endDate)); 

var startDate1 = moment('2018-02-27')
var endDate1 = moment('2018-03-01')
console.log('Diff in non leap year',getDiff(startDate1, endDate1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you would only want to subtract if the leap day falls between the start and end dates

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

- Check if the selected year is a leap year.
- If yes, check if date range covers `29th Feb`
- If yes, subtract 1 else 0

```js
function getDiff(startDate, endDate){
  var dayToExclude = moment('29/02/' + startDate.year(), 'DD/MM/YYYY');
  var excludeDays = startDate.isLeapYear() && startDate.isBefore(dayToExclude) && endDate.isAfter(dayToExclude) ? 1 : 0;
  return endDate.diff(startDate, 'days') - excludeDays;
}


var startDate = moment('2020-02-27')
var endDate = moment('2020-03-01')
console.log('Diff in leap year', getDiff(startDate, endDate)); 

var startDate1 = moment('2018-02-27')
var endDate1 = moment('2018-03-01')
console.log('Diff in non leap year',getDiff(startDate1, endDate1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```